# How can I get my microphone to work

Tags: sound, microphone

I can't get my microphone working on Ubuntu 11.10, I tried all the hardware profiles in the audio settings. without any success.

I am sure that i don't have any issue with my mic or input since I have dual boot and I got it working on  windows.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 2):

try going into Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type `alsamixer` and hitting return. Is the mic volume high enough? I found that my microphone would default to zero volume for some reason in this, despite it being full in the settings.

The default view in alsamixer is master levels, so it might be best to press F4 to show capture levels. Then (on mine anyway) whenever I have restarted my computer internal mic level is 0 - try using the left/right arrow keys to highlight internal mic, up and down to choose level (press h to get a list of keys to adjust settings)